# Print file contents using cat in subprocess

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I am using a subprocess call in python where I have to print a file contents using `cat`. The file name is a variable that I generate in the python code itself. This is my code:

```
pid = str(os.getpid())
tmp_file_path = "/tmp/" + pid + "/data_to_synnet"
synnet_output = subprocess.check_output(["cat echo '%s'"%tmp_file_path], shell=True)
```

The above code throws an error saying `cat: echo: No such file or directory`.

However, when I use only `subprocess.check_output(["echo '%s'"%tmp_file_path], shell=True)`, the variable name is printed correctly.

Also, I tried doing this (`cat echo $tmp_file_name`) in the command line and it works. Can someone please tell what is wrong?

Comment: `cat` is trying to open a file called `echo`.  Why are you using `echo`?  When I try `cat echo $tmp_file_name` on the command-line I get `cat: echo: No such file or directory` - you must have a file called echo in your current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you want is this:

```
"cat '%s'"%tmp_file_path
```

Just get rid of the "echo" word.

Alternatively,

```
 synnet_output = subprocess.check_output(["cat", tmp_file_path], shell=False)
```

Comment: Might be worth saying that `shell=False` is valid since `echo` is a shell built-in and so the shell is not needed (`/bin/echo` would be used otherwise).